# Python NET call C# method and pass a null as argument

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, null, python.net

I'm having the following static C# method

```
public static double[] TestMethod(double[] a, double[] b)
```

which I would like to call from Python using the Python NET package.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("MyCSharp")
import System
from MyCSharp import MyStaticClass

t1 = MyStaticClass.MyTestMethod([1., 2.], [3., 4.]) # works
```

But how can I pass `null` for the first or second argument?

```
t2 = MyStaticClass.MyTestMethod(None, [3., 4.]) # fails! TypeError: No method matches given arguments

t3 = MyStaticClass.MyTestMethod([1., 2.], None) # fails! TypeError: No method matches given arguments
```

I know that I could add additional C# methods for the cases when argument `a` or be `b` are `null`.

```
public static double[] TestMethodWithANull(double[] b)
{ return TestMethod(null, b); }

public static double[] TestMethodWithBNull(double[] a)
{ return TestMethod(a, null); }
```

But I would prefer to pass a `null` from Python to the C# method. For example in MATLAB I can do that by passing a `[]`.

Comment: another alternative may be: `public static double[] TestMethod(double[] a = null, double[] b = null)`